# Flutter como asociar archivos json con un tap en android

Tags: json, flutter

Estoy usando flutter 3.13
La app se usa por ahora solo en android
Estoy usando archivos json que los usuarios lo comparten mayormente por WhatsApp.

Lo que necesito es que si el usuario hace tap en el archivo abra mi app.
Actualmente el teléfono android dice
"Puede que no dispongas de una app para este tipo de archivo".

Por favor si alguien me puede ayudar.

Desde ya muchas gracias